# What is this black insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]  I found it in my computer but I don't know what it is

Comment: Please provide your location and the approximate size of the bug you found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [Boxelder bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxelder_bug), which are common in areas of North America with maples, ash, or other host trees:

[image: boxelder bug] *(photo by Katja Schulz via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eastern_Boxelder_Bug_-_Flickr_-_treegrow.jpg))*

Comment: A hemipteran, yes, but the OP's specimen has quite different color patterns than the species you suggest. Can you explain the difference in colors or provide stronger support for why *Boisea trivittata* is the correct answer despite these morphological differences?